# How to free memory used by VideoView

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I have been having this issue for a while now.
I have a simple application that plays a playlist of videos within a videoview with a pause of a few seconds between them.

```
private final Runnable playNormalVideo = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            final String filepath = ...;
            viewVideo.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    onEndVideo(false);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            viewVideo.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    onEndVideo(false);
                }
            });
            viewVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    viewVideo.start();
                }
            });
            viewVideo.setVideoPath(filepath);
            viewVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewVideo.requestFocus();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String error = Utils.getStackTrace(e);
            Utils.log(true, error);
        }
    }
};
```

and in my `onEndVideo()` function I make the `background` visible and check what video to play next and with a `Handler` i request to play it after x seconds. 
**My issue is the following** :
Within a long run (approx 1 day) the background becomes invisible within a lot of seconds before the video starts. I don't understand why. If someone could help me get rid of this issue.
I also thought I should free memory between video plays but i don't seem to find how to do that.
**Note** : All the videos are saved on the device.
Thanks for any help.